# Defining and using a list of Ball Trees via the sklearn python package

Tags: scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I have defined a list of ball tree objects as below, where `input1` is a NumPy array with shape (100, 320).

```
bt = []
bt.append(BallTree(input1))
```

I take one of the elements of `input1` as a sample query, where `sample_index` is assumed to be within bounds.

```
sample_query = input1[sample_index,:]

# Find nearest neighbour and compute distance and index
distance, index = bt[0].query(sample_query,1)
```

Here, `distance[0]` is 0 as expected given that 'sample_query' is a member of `input1`.

```
# Adding another BallTree instance to the list
#input2 is a numpy array with shape (70,320)  
bt.append(BallTree(input2))
distance, index = bt[0].query(sample_query,1)
print distance[0]
# Output here is NOT zero (NOT expected!!)
```

Why would the nearest neighbour distance change for 'sample_query' and bt[0]  when I append one more Ball tree object to the Ball tree list 'bt'? I would expect the object bt[0] to be unmodified when I append one more object to the list bt. Is my expectation correct?

Comment: Hi Archith. Could you please provide a self-contained example (i.e. including the input arrays, imports etc), preferably in a github gist?
This is really not the expected behavior.

Comment: Hi Andreas. Thanks for replying. I found a gap in my understanding of BallTree with this example. After a bit of digging, I now understand that  (borrowing from the notation in the question) bt[0].data actually points to the input numpy array rather than it being a copy. I was re-using the input numpy array for creating further ball trees and hence the data as seen by bt[0] kept getting clobbered everytime. If I ensure that the numpy array gets created (or allocated in 'C-speak') for each  ball tree instance, ball tree query results are consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a gap in my understanding of BallTree with this example.

After a bit of digging, I now understand that (borrowing from the notation in the question) bt[0].data actually points to the input numpy array rather than it being a copy. I was re-using the input numpy array for creating further ball trees and hence the data as seen by bt[0] kept getting clobbered everytime.

If I ensure that the numpy array gets created (or allocated in 'C-speak') for each ball tree instance, ball tree query results are consistent.

Comment: Indeed, this sounds like an API bug. I think the constructor should be `BallTree(data, copy=True)` by default so as to make the BallTree keep it's own independent copy of the data by default while allowing the user to avoid the copy if he/she does not have enough memory and knows that she should not update the data when `copy=False`.

Please feel free to open an issue on the github issue tracker for the scikit-learn project: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues

Answer (score 2):

You are still doing the query on the same ball tree instance `bt[0]` in both cases hence you are getting the same results twice which is to be expected. I don't understand why you put BallTree instances in a python list BTW.

Comment: Well, the problem was that I don't see the same results twice. Anyways, I understood where I was going wrong. I have described it in my reply to Andreas. I needed a way to access indexed ball trees based on certain characteristics of the query. There might be better ways of going about it though.